# What does 에 mean here?

Tags: grammar, translation

In this expression:
"한국에서, 지켜야 할 예절에는, 어떤 것이 있을까요?"

Question:
 1. Why is ~에 attached to 예절? What meaning does it add?

Answer (score 2):

In this sentence, `있다` is adjective and means "to be included in certain range or the whole". An adverb with postposition `-에` should be used in this case.

Also, we can regard `지켜야 할 예절` as "the list of proprieties to observe" because Korean is not sensitive to numbers. With this consideration, the sentence means "What is included in the list of proprieties to observe?"

So, the sentence can be translated into "What kind of proprieties should we observe 
in Korea?"

`는` indicates the theme of the sentence.

Comment: I don't understand. You said 있다 is an adjective but the only 있다 i see is "있을까요" which is a verb.

Comment: Both verb and adjective can be predicate in Korean, and the conjugation form is the same. 있다 has a lot of meanings, some of them are verb and the others are adjective. In this case, 있다 is adjective.